# Difficulty with Java array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SecuritySystem{


   ArrayList<SecureMessage> listOfSecureMessages = new ArrayList(); //List of all the messages.
   ArrayList<String> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<String>(); //List of all the users.

   //Initialising some users
   listOfUsers.add("Max");
   listOfUsers.add("Ksenia");
   listOfUsers.add("Sally");
   listOfUsers.add("Ali");
   listOfUsers.add("Tyrone");  
}
```

So I'm trying to write a program that stores messages, usernames, etc in java. It consists of 3 classes, and one class requires arrays

For my code above, I'm trying to allow this public class, SecuritySystem, to store an arraylist of references to a different class, SecureMessage (and its objects).

And I'm trying to allow functionality like allowing methods to search through SecureMessage

The above code is what I got so far. It has a pre-populated second arraylist of strings containing user names for the messages. But I'm getting errors with it saying "package listofusers does not exist" and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

First time really learning Java, so any assistance would be appreciated !

Comment: Well, the code shown has no `listofusers` mentioned anywhere. Either you got the error wrong (listOfUsers) or are not showing the right code.

Comment: You need to put the add call inside a method, maybe the constructor could be a nice place for it.

Answer (score -1):

let's think in a easy way , and used concept of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) , firstly , you may create a class that holds what you want (as u said above a SecureMessage) , then we'll pass to the second class that use the first class , more precisely , first class will be a tool of the second class ,